# I keep getting an error called 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my code I don't need to replace numbers, only things like parenthesis and dashes and I thought I spec ifoed that in my code but it still doesnt work. Here is the code:

```
def standardize_phone_number(phone_number):
    phone_number = str(phone_number.replace('(', '')\
                         .replace(')', '')\
                         .replace(' ', '')\
                         .replace('-', ''))

    if not (phone_number.isdigit() and len(phone_number) == 10):
        return None

    if phone_number[0] == '(' and phone_number[4:6] == ')' and \
       phone_number[9] == '-' and len(phone_number) == 13:
        return phone_number.replace('(', '').replace(')', '-')

    if phone_number[3] == '-' and phone_number[7] == '-' and \
       len(phone_number) == 11:
        return phone_number.replace('-', '').replace('-', '')

    if phone_number[5] == ' ' and phone_number[9] == '-' and \
       len(phone_number) == 13:
        return phone_number.replace(' ', '').replace('-', '')
    else:
        return None
print(standardize_phone_number(123-456-7890))
```

Comment: Hello noah! There are a few mistakes here. The first I can think of is `123-456-7890` that is passed to your function. This is not a string and phone-numbers are often represented as strings. Use: `"123-456-7890"`. My second recommendation is to google `Verify phone numbers with regex python` (and similar phrases) and get an understanding about what regex is and how it can help you here. It will save you lots of time.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're passing an `int` as input to `standardize_phone_number`, specifically the `int` `123-456-7890`, which is `-8223`, while `standardize_phone_number` expects a string.

What you want instead is:

```
standardize_phone_number('123-456-7890')
```

**Edit:** On Returning `None`

With the input above, your code will reach the final `else` and therefore, return `None`. Since you strip out all occurrences of the characters `'('`, `')'`, `' '`, and `'-'`, the `phone_number` string will just be the digits entered (assuming a valid phone number format is entered). So none of your `if` conditions will ever evaluate to `True`.

It looks like you are meaning to remove all instances of the characters `'('`, `')'`, `' '`, and `'-'` from a phone number and just return the digits of the phone number. In that case you can reduce your code to:

```
def standardize_phone_number(phone_number):
    phone_number = str(phone_number.replace('(', '')\
                         .replace(')', '')\
                         .replace(' ', '')\
                         .replace('-', ''))

    if phone_number.isdigit() and len(phone_number) == 10:
        return phone_number
    else:
        raise ValueError("The number you entered is not a valid phone number")
```

With `re.sub` you can compact all those `replace` calls into one:

```
import re

def standardize_phone_number(phone_number):
    phone_number = re.sub(r'[()\s-]', '',  phone_number)
    if phone_number.isdigit() and len(phone_number) == 10:
        return phone_number
    else:
        raise ValueError("The number you entered is not a valid phone number")
```

Of course, the `ValueError` is optional, you can implement whatever handling you think is right for invalid phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks it at least runs now, but it's returning none instead of the number.

Comment: @NoahAbrica I made an edit to the post, hopefully it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

change you calling method

```
print(standardize_phone_number(123-456-7890))
```

from this to

```
print(standardize_phone_number('123-456-7890'))
```

Then it will work properly because only string object having the method "replace()"

Comment: Thanks it at least runs now, but it's returning none instead of the number.

Comment: HI @noha. its mistake of your code your given phone number length is 12 digit and i didn't  saw the length of 12 in your and conditions in decision making

Comment: you need the the nubers only from a particular format of string right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks that phone_number is a digit, then returns none if it is not.
After applying suggestions from this post, it will always return None since now phone_number will always be a string.

```
if not (phone_number.isdigit() and len(phone_number) == 10):
    return None
```

comment out those 2 lines, it should solve your recurring problem.